# What are the suttas in which the Buddha provides instruction on how to meditate?

Tags: the-buddha, sutras, texts, meditation, practice

What are the actual suttas in which the Buddha described how to meditate? A list of all such suttas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To straighten view before meditation: [Samma,ditthi Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/11.14-Sammaditthi-S-m9-piya.pdf)

- Anapana

  - [Anapanasati Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapanasati_Sutta)
- Satipatthana

  - [Satipatthana Sutta and Mahāsatipaṭṭhāna Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satipatthana_Sutta)
  - [Kayagatasati Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayagatasati_Sutta)
  - [Saṅkhitta Dhamma Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/46.6-Sankhitta-Dhamma-S-a8.63-piya.pdf)
- Elements / properties

  - [Dhātu Vibhaṅga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/4.17-Dhatu-Vibhanga-S-m140-piya.pdf)
  - [Titth’ayatana Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.8-Titthayatana-S-a03.61-piya.pdf)
  - [Maha Hatthi,padapama Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.16-Maha-Hatthipadopama-S-m028-piya.pdf)
  - [Bahu Dhātuka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/29.1a-Bahudhatuka-S-m115-piya.pdf)
- Reflective / perception based

  - [Giri-m-ananda Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/19.16-Girimananda-S-a10.60-piya.pdf)
  - [Indriya Bhāvanā Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.13-Indriya-Bhavana-S-m152-piya.pdf)
  - [Amba,latthika Rahul’ovada Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/3.10-Ambalatthika-Rahulovada-S-m061-piya.pdf)
- Metta, Karuna, Mudita, Upekka

  - [Saṅkhitta Dhamma Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/46.6-Sankhitta-Dhamma-S-a8.63-piya.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

My favorite sutta on meditation is [Cula-suññata Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.121.than.html) (The Lesser Discourse on Emptiness). Thanissaro Bhikkhu provides a good commentary on this in his article [The Integrity of Emptiness](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/integrityofemptiness.html), the section called "Emptiness as an Approach to Meditation".

The two other suttas everyone else mentions - Anapanasati and Satipatthana suttas - are very good too.

There are also nice tidbits in the Northern recording of the Anapanasati Sutta, called [Ānāpānasmṛti Sutra](http://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0125_LL_17-01_anapanasmrti) from Ekottarika Āgama.

Also, if you are specifically into Jhana meditation, then [Samadhanga Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.028.than.html) provides the canonical definitions of the Four Jhanas.

Answer (score 4):

Two notable suttas in which Buddha provided meditation instructions are:

1. [Satipatthana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/soma/wayof.html)
2. [Anapanasati Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html)

Additionally, the [Karaniya Metta Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/buddharakkhita/wheel365.html#ch1) addresses the practice of mettā meditation.

Answer (score 3):

Gelanna Sutta is the sutta through which Buddha provides instructions on how to meditate. Other forms of meditations are Anapanasati sutta,Satipatthana sutta, Bhikkhunuppasaya Sutta.

In Buddhism, the Tripitaka (in Pali) is earliest collection of Buddhist teachings and the only text recognized as canonical by Theravada Buddhists. Tripitaka means 'three baskets' from the way in which it was originally recorded: text was written on long, narrow leaves, which were sewn at edges and grouped into bunches and stored in baskets.

Comment: The [Gelanna Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.007.than.html) which you mentioned is recommended for people who are sick or dying. Another is the [Anathapindikovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.143.than.html).

Answer (score 0):

majjhima nikāya 20. Vitakkasaṇṭhānasutta --> I use/belive this to be sutta about samma voyamma. After reading the suttas I am not convinced/sure about any explanation about what is samma sati or samma samdhi.

Comment: samma sati or samma samdhi are explained in majjhima nikāya 117